# Display selectmenu inside jQuery confirm

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, select, jquery-confirm

i have a jQUery-confirm and im trying to display some content which have a select and my select.selectMenu() doesn't seem to work because it's being displayed inside the jQUery-confirm. It's just showing the default select.I can easily call .selectMenu() on a select outside the scope and it will change from select to a selectmenu. Example:

HTML:

```
 <div id="aDiv"> 
     <select id="aSelect"> <option value="1"> 1 </option></select>
 </div>
 <button type="button" id="aButton">Click </button>
```

CSS:

```
#aDiv {
     display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#aSelect').selectmenu();
  var divVar = $('#aDiv');
  $('#aButton').on("click", function() {
       $.confirm( {
            title: 'Hello',
            content: '',
            onOpen : function() {
                divVar.show();
                this.setContent(divVar);
            },
            onClose : function() {
               divVar.hide();
            }

         });
     });
 });
```

How do i make jquery-confirm show jquery ui widgets like selectmenu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, you need to add html markup inside jconfirm and initialize the selectMenu plugin, its better to write the markup inside content instead of defining it outside.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // $('#aSelect').selectMenu();
    $('#aButton').on("click", function() {
        $.confirm( {
            title: 'Hello',
            content: function(){
                return $('#aDiv').html(); // put in the #aSelect html, 
            },
            onContentReady : function() {
                this.$content.find('#aSelect').selectMenu(); // initialize the plugin when the model opens.
            },
            onClose : function() {

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It somewhat worked but now i have a new problem. the drop-down menu is behind the jquery content window , look here: http://imgur.com/a/ayoJz. Also selectMenu() needs to be .selectmenu()  :)

Comment: i was thinking maybe `.ui-selectmenu-menu {
  z-index: 9999; 
 }` in the CSS would solve the problem but i was wrong, it didn't work.

Comment: how do I get the z-index of jquery-confirm $.confirm window?

Comment: z-index for jconfirm is set to 99999999, set `.ui-selectmenu-menu` higher to it.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

You have missed the **#** for **id**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#aSelect').selectMenu();
  var divVar = $('#aDiv');
  $('#aButton').on("click", function() {
       $.confirm( {
            title: 'Hello',
            content: '',
            onOpen : function() {
                divVar.show();
                this.setContent(divVar);
            },
            onClose : function() {
               divVar.hide();
            }

         });
     });
 });
```

Comment: Forgot to add '#' in example, i've them in my original code, edited the question